# Is there any inbulit function for degree to radian?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, math

Is there any inbulit class/function which converts degree to radian and wise versa. I am not sluggy to write one. But, this requirement is inevitable in so many places. So, I guess there must be some inbulit function to do these things. Can anybody say about this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. There is always `(x / 180.0) * Math.PI`